# Rest API design: Managing access to sub-entities

Tags: rest, http, api-design

*Note: I realize that this is close to being off-topic for being opinion-based, but I am hoping that there is some accepted best practice to handle this that I just don't know about.*

My problem is the following: I need to design a Rest API for a program where users can create their own projects, and each project contains files that can only be seen by users that have access. I am stuck with how to design the "List all files of a project" query.

Standard Rest API practice would suggest two endpoints, like:

```
`GET /projects`     # List all projects
`POST /projects`    # Create new project
`GET /projects/id`  # Get specific project
etc.
```

and the same for the files of a project.

However, there should never be a reason to list *all* files - only the files of a single project. To make it more complicated, access management needs to be a thing, users should never see files that are in projects they don't have access to.

I can see multiple ways to handle that:

1. So the obvious way is to implement the GET function, optionally with a filter. However, this isn't optimal, since if the user doesn't set a filter, it would have to crawl through all projects, check for each project whether the user has access, and then list all files the user has access to:

   `GET /files?project=test1`
2. I could also make the files command a subcommand of the projects command - e.g.

   `GET /projects/#id/files`

   However, I have the feeling this isn't too restful, since it doesn't expose entities directly?

Is there any concencus on which should usually be implemented? Is it okay to "force" users to set a parameter in the first one? Or is there a third alternative that solves what I am looking for? Happy about any literature recommendations on how to design this as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Standard Rest API practice would suggest two endpoints

No, it wouldn't.  REST practice would suggest figuring out the resources in your resource model.

Think "documents": I should be able to retrieve (GET) a document that describes all of the files in the project.  Great!  This document should only be accessible when the request authorization matches some access control list.  Also good.

Maybe there should also be a document for each user, so they can see a list of all of the projects they have access to, where that document includes links to the "all of the files in the project" documents.  And of course that document should also be subject to access control.

Note that "documents" here might be text, or media files, or scripts, or CSS, or pretty much any kind of information that you can transmit over the network.  We can gloss the details, because "uniform interface" means that we manage them all the same way.

In other words, we're just designing a "web site" filled with interlinked documents, with access control.

Each document is going to need a unique identifier.  That identifier can be anything we want: `/5393d5b0-0517-4c13-a821-c6578cb97668` is *fine*.  Because it can be anything we want, we have extra degrees of freedom.

For example, we might design our identifiers such that the document whose identifiers begin with `/users/12345` are only accessible by requests with authorization headers that match user 12345, and that all documents whose identifiers begin with `/projects/12345` are only accessible by requests with authorization headers that match any of the users that have access to that specific project, and so on.

In other words, it is completely acceptable to choose resource identifier spellings that make your implementation easier.

(Note: in an ideal world, you would have "cool" identifiers that are implementation agnostic, so that they still work even if you change the underlying implementation details of your server.)

> I have the feeling this isn't too restful, since it doesn't expose entities directly?

It's fine.  Resource models and entity models are *different* things; we shouldn't expect them to always match one to one.

Answer (score 1):

After looking further, I came across [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/api-design) from Microsoft. Some quotes:

> Also consider the relationships between different types of resources and how you might expose these associations. For example, the /customers/5/orders might represent all of the orders for customer 5. You could also go in the other direction, and represent the association from an order back to a customer with a URI such as /orders/99/customer. However, extending this model too far can become cumbersome to implement. A better solution is to provide navigable links to associated resources in the body of the HTTP response message. This mechanism is described in more detail in the section Use HATEOAS to enable navigation to related resources.

> In more complex systems, it can be tempting to provide URIs that enable a client to navigate through several levels of relationships, such as /customers/1/orders/99/products. However, this level of complexity can be difficult to maintain and is inflexible if the relationships between resources change in the future. Instead, try to keep URIs relatively simple. Once an application has a reference to a resource, it should be possible to use this reference to find items related to that resource. The preceding query can be replaced with the URI /customers/1/orders to find all the orders for customer 1, and then /orders/99/products to find the products in this order.

This makes me think that using solution 2 is probably the best case for me, since each file will be associated with only a single project, and should be deleted when a project is deleted. Files cannot exist on their own, outside of projects.